# Set value in child component that uses ControlValueAccessor from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I apply a child component (which uses ControlValueAccessor) in the parent and the write something in the child component, everything is passed on to the parent accordingly.

However if I try to write something in the parent component and then pass it on to the child component, nothing is available in the input. How can I fix this?

Just to be clear this is what the preferred behavior is supposed to be:

```
child string value = written in child
parent string value = written in child
```

but whenever I type in text in the parent input I get the following:

```
child string value = (empty)
parent string value = written in parent
```

[app.component.ts]

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  external = "";
}
```

[app.component.html]

```
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<app-custom-input [(ngModel)]="external" name="externalVal"></app-custom-input>
<input [(ngModel)]="external"/>
external: {{ external }}
```

[custom-input.component.ts]

```
import { Component, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: '<input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};
  val = "";

  set value(val) {
    if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.onChange(val);
      this.onTouch(val);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
}
```

Also available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ker4g5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input%2Fcustom-input.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you did not define a **getter** for `value`. So you'd have to modify your code as follows:

#### custom-input.component.ts

```js
set value (val) {
  /* ... */
}

get value () {
  return this.val
}
```

This is a simplified example:

```js
o = {
 _n: null,
 set name (v) {
   this._n = v;
 },
 get name () {
   return this._n;
 }
}

// Setter
o.name = 'foo'

// Getter
// Without `get name()` -> `undefined`
o.name
```

Comment: I just tried it out and you're absolutely right. Thanks a bunch!